# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Dex archives: setting .DEX extension only for .CLASS files

Tags: android, build, continuous-integration, kotlin, gitlab

I build the project at gitlab ci

```
./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace
```

and sometimes it throws an error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Dex archives: setting .DEX extension only for .CLASS files
```

At my local pc it works correctly.

kotlin version is 1.2

multidex is enabled

What is the reason of this error?

Comment: have you enables mutlidex true and added library for mutlidex?

Comment: yes, i've edited the question

Comment: @m.myalkin Found any solution?

Comment: @AndiGeeky, no, exception did not appear several days

Comment: I am seeing this issue on buddybuild but on my local development machine it works fine.  Any ideas are appreciated.  I tried enabling multidexing but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Delete app/build file and then run the app

Comment: @ashraful I run it at CI server, there is no build directory because every build is clean

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems I found the solution.
At the build moment gradle was showing warnings for me:

```
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.

app: 'androidProcessor' dependencies won't be recognized as kapt annotation processors. Please change the configuration name to 'kapt' for these artifacts: 'com.arello-mobile:moxy-compiler:1.5.3' and apply the kapt plugin: "apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'".
```

I made a misspelling and forgot to remove unnecessary annotationProcessor for library:

```
annotationProcessor "com.arello-mobile:moxy-compiler:$moxyVersion"
kapt "com.arello-mobile:moxy-compiler:$moxyVersion"
```

So I removed first line.

After that I applied kapt plugin `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` and fixed some build errors in code after it.

After all I realized that I forgot to replace `compile` to `implementation` in some places. It is weird but without it build didn't work.

This changes fix my error build.

Answer (score 116):

`./gradlew clean` fixed the same error for me.

Comment: No need to clean build and waste time. Better to just restart Android Studio.

Comment: @VinayakGarg: The asker mentions they are building via gitlab ci, so Android Studio is irrelevant here.

Comment: in a cordova project use `./platforms/android/gradlew clean`

Comment: Or in a cordova project use `cordova clean`

Comment: Or in Flutter use `flutter clean`

Answer (score 58):

For **Cordova** developers,

If you get this build error in your project, as said [Pierrick Martellière](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4034886/pierrick-martelli%c3%a8re) in the comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48232296/3452348), in you project folder use :

```
cordova clean
```

It makes a cleaning and a build immediately

Comment: Yep, this is the fix for Cordova projects. You can also just clean android side by adding `android` at the end of that command.

Answer (score 9):

> Simple Solution

For Ionic and Cordove Projects

```
cordova clean
```

Answer (score 4):

Above answer is mostly right but in my case, i get this exception when i crate same name **java** and **kotlin** file then deletes one of them.

Solutions are: just **Build -> Clean Project**  my project and it works. And my project also enabled **multiDex**.

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned above by @mixel cleaning gets the job done. But as an option not to do it manually just add the gradle 'clean' task into app run configuration so it will be done all the time before launch. Of cource, it can slow down the whole process a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Configuring for multidexing did not solve this issue for me.

However I did come up with a resolution...of sorts.  Basically it involved creating a pull request for a second branch on the same commit as the build that was failing.  The build for this pull request succeeded, and then Bitbucket thought that the original pull request was ok and allowed us to merge, even though we had made no changes on that branch.  There is some unexplained weirdness there but the technique worked.

Here's how I did it:

Assume that the branch that is failing is called `bad-branch`.

I created a new branch called `bad-branch-copy` on the commit that was common between `bad-branch` and `develop`.  Then I merged `bad-branch` into `bad-branch-copy`.  The end result of this was a fast forward such that `bad-branch-copy` ended up on the same commit as `bad-branch`.  I was expecting a separate commit so this result surprised me, but I was grasping at straws anyway so I kept going.

I then pushed `bad-branch-copy` to GitHub and created a pull request from `bad-branch-copy` to `develop`.  This triggered a build on `bad-branch-copy` -> `develop`, which was successful.

At that point, buddybuild showed a successful build on `bad-branch-copy` -> `develop` and still showed a failure on `bad-branch` -> `develop`.  However, Bitbucket showed a successful build on the pull request for `bad-branch`.  Yes, that's right: buddybuild showed a failure but Bitbucket said it was ok.

We were then able to merge the `bad-branch` pull request and all was well with the world.  Please don't ask me why, I will not answer. :)

I think the same thing could be accomplished with

```
git checkout bad-build
git checkout -b bad-build-copy
git push origin bad-build-copy
```

followed by creating a pull request for bad-build-copy.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the problem to go away by closing and restarting Android Studio.  Perhaps even a Rebuild Project would have done it as well (did not try that though).

Comment: Rebuild does it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Currently using **Android Studio 3.3.2** I just disabled the instant run and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

What resolved the issue for me was manually adding all the conflicting files manually. For example in my gradle file I had:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
```

it was underlined with red. I hovered over the line and android studio said there was a conflict with another file using a lower version. The error was similar to

> come.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.1 conflicts/mix versions with 27.1.1.

It gave me the names of the files and I manually added them with the corresponding version so they would all match

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the current solutions worked for me and it was fixed by simply disabling `Instant Run`.

Answer (score 0):

On react native,

I just

```
cd android/ && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && yarn android
```

this did thee trick for me.

Answer (score -4):

please find here the solution of this problem,

```
 defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Have you added multidex dependencies, as per I wrote in code?

Comment: yes, of course, I used `com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2`

Comment: Ok, please follow this steps

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html